# Using `-Wno-implicit-fallthrough` on older versions of gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, suppress-warnings, gcc-warning, fall-through

I have a project which builds fine under gcc 4.8.4. I tried building using gcc 7, and noticed a lot of `-Wimplicit-fallthrough=` warnings. [As far as I'm aware](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/10/wimplicit-fallthrough-in-gcc-7/), this was indeed added in gcc version 7. I'm now using `-Wno-implicit-fallthrough` when building to suppress these warnings. Moving back to the older version of gcc, keeping the `-Wno-implicit-fallthrough` compiler flag does *not* lead to any error, even though I do not believe that gcc 4 recognizes this option. How come? Are specifically the `-Wno-` options allowed to not be recognized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `man gcc`:

> When an unrecognized warning option is requested (e.g.,
>          -Wunknown-warning), GCC emits a diagnostic stating that the option is
>          not recognized.  However, if the -Wno- form is used, the behavior is
>          slightly different: no diagnostic is produced for -Wno-unknown-warning
>          unless other diagnostics are being produced.  This allows the use of
>          new -Wno- options with old compilers, but if something goes wrong, the
>          compiler warns that an unrecognized option is present.

To sum it up: if all goes well, unknown `-Wno-*` switches are ignored to preserve compatibility.